# Nunit 3.2.1 Tests not discovered on Visual Studio Test explorer

Tags: nunit

This is my configuration:

1. Visual Studio Enterprise 2015
2. NUnit 3.2.1
3. NUnit3 Test Adapter 3.0.10 (Installed as Extensions and Updates as well as through nuget package manager in project)
4. Target Framework is set to 4.5

Build succeeds fine but test discovery shows an error and 0 tests are discovered.

Error log:

```
Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown discovering tests in C:\projects\~
The NUnit 3.0 driver does not support the portable version of NUnit.
Use a platform specific runner.
NUnit Adapter 3.0.10.0: Test discovery complete.
Discover test finished: 0 found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running the NUnit **3** Adapter (correct name) version 3.0.10, you are using NUnit 3.0.1 to run your tests. If the tests use the 3.2.1 framework, then there is some chance of an incompatibility. NUnit runners are always backward compatible. For example, you could use NUnit 3.2 to run NUnit 3.0 tests, but the reverse is not true.

The message you are seeing is actually misleading and was changed in the code recently. It assumes you are runing a portable test when a serialization exception occurs.

Comment: I'm running the NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0 and have tests using the 3.2.1 framework. Still seeing this message:
    NUnit Adapter 3.2.0.0: Test discovery starting
    Exception NUnit.Engine.NUnitEngineException, Exception thrown discovering tests in
Any idea? Or not related?

Comment: Not really related, since it's a different exception. I would need more info to give an answer to this one.